# Magento 2 : Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: magento2, upgrade, version

Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver, Argument 2 passed to Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver::__construct() must be of the type array, null given

[image]
This error is appearing on the product page,
after I have upgraded Magento 2.3 to 2.4

not sure if its a version issue

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screenshot, the error is from the third party extension.

Kindly disable this extension :

> app/code/Amasty/Shopby

Run all the commands like upgrade, deploy and compilation one's and then check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dhiren, i can not disable it as many other modules are dependent on this module.

Comment: It seems like elastic search issue.

Comment: you need to just disable for the debug purpose and then you can reenable it or install extension updated version which compitible with new magento version.

Comment: Its the latest version of module.
i ma using php 7.3 on magento 2.4.3 which runs on 7.4
is that possible cause of issue ?

Comment: any thoughts @Dhiren ?

Comment: not an issues of php 7.3 version. that is already supported.

Comment: oh okay
one question
i am getting this error
#11 Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList->getFilters() called at [app/code/Amasty/Shopby/Model/Layer/FilterList.php:164]

Comment: In code its $filters = parent::getFilters($layer);

I don't find this getFilters method in parent class (i.e /magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php)

Comment: though this code is not even calling.

Comment: I already told this things : you need to just disable for the debug purpose and then you can re enable it or install extension updated version which compatible with new magento version.

Comment: Thankyou @Dhiren

Comment: If answer help you, please upvote and accept as solution. so it will help other in community.